# Access url without token in Firebase Storage

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-storage

I have a firebase storage download url, like

https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/siren-5eee7.appspot.com/o/profile%2FC6jNlR0F4cZBPv7wF0REWUNVor33?alt=media&token=63a9130e-2ba6-4f38-ac3f-2231c54a1043

How can I access this url without token parameter?

For example, If I access above url without token there will be 403 error showing permisson denied.

My firebase storage secure rule is below :

```
service firebase.storage {
  match /b/{bucket}/o {
    match /{allPaths=**} {
      allow read, write: if request.auth != null;
    }
  }
}
```

This file located in `/etc` file. How can I do it?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Try changing rule:

```
service firebase.storage {
  match /b/{bucket}/o {
    match /{allPaths=**} {
      allow read;
      allow write: if request.auth != null;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Media token still shows up even after chaning the rules to this. Any idea why?

Comment: This doesn´t cut it. Changing that rule won't make any difference.

Answer (score 16):

From what I understand, you're trying to make the whole bucket publicly available. Using Firebase access rules might not be best, you might want to make the bucket read access available via Google Cloud's Storage layer.

To do that, one of the easiest way is using the [Google Cloud Console Storage](https://console.cloud.google.com/storage/browser).

Select the bucket, click the bucket to configure and open the permissions tab.
Since this is Firebase managed bucket, it would have what Google called fine-grained access control. Don't worry, adding public access is quite simple.
Click Add members button, then, on the sidebar, add in `allUsers` as new member, and give it the role of Storage > Storage Object Viewer. You can see more detail in the [Storage Docs](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/making-data-public#buckets).

This will make the bucket publicly viewable via `<bucketname>.storage.googleapis.com`.
If you created extra bucket in Firebase that match a domain you own and verified in [Google Search Console](https://search.google.com/search-console/welcome), you can create a bucket of named after your custom domain and have it publicly accessible using a CNAME of the custom domain that points to `c.storage.googleapis.com.` (This would only works for HTTP, not HTTPS). You can see more detail at [Storage Endpoints Docs](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/request-endpoints), Google Cloud's docs explain it much better than I can. Hope this helps!

Comment: This is great! The simplest, best (and maybe the only) answer about this online.

Comment: How come this is not the right answer? This method works. Go to the bucket open it, select the permission tab, and look for grant access. Select allUsers from the drop-down and select the role as Cloud Storage > Storage Object Viewer. Then there will be a warning regarding making the bucket public.

Comment: I think its `allUsers`, plural?

Comment: Yes, it should be allUsers. I'm editing the answer.

Answer (score 10):

In case you need the rule to `allow accessing only the images` without a token you have to do the following:

```
service firebase.storage {
  match /b/{bucket}/o {
    match /{allPaths=**} {
      allow read: if request.auth!=null || resource.contentType.matches('image/.*');
      allow write: if request.auth!=null;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

If you need to access to certain url (image) without token parameter use the rule below:

```
rules_version = '2';
service firebase.storage {
  match /b/{bucket}/o {
    match /images/users/default.png {
      allow read;
    }
    match /{allPaths=**} {
      allow read, write: if request.auth != null;
    }
  }
}
```

If you need to access to certain folder without token parameter use the rule below:

```
rules_version = '2';
service firebase.storage {
  match /b/{bucket}/o {
    match /images/{wildcardpath=**} {
      allow read;
    }
    match /{allPaths=**} {
      allow read, write: if request.auth != null;
    }
  }
}
```

---

Note: Change the url or folder to yours

Comment: Here is a helpful guide https://www.techotopia.com/index.php/A_Guide_to_Firebase_Cloud_Storage_Security_Rules