# Is getDownloadUrl a paid operation?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, firebase-storage

I am trying to find out if `getDownloadUrl` on Firebase storage / Google Cloud Storage (a method to get the public URL for a file on the storage) is a paid operation. Even after reading through [the documentation](https://cloud.google.com/storage/pricing#operations-pricing), I'm not sure if it is a free operation or a Class B operation.

So can anyone tell me: Is fetchinig the URL for a file on the storage via `getDownloadUrl` a paid operation?

Comment: Just out of curiosity how many millions of files are you planning to retrieve for this to become an issue ? :)

Comment: If the files are public, you don't need to use `getDownloadUrl` at all. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58443123/firebase-storage-using-download-url-instead-of-storage-ref/58443247#58443247

Answer (score 13):

There is no charge for calling `getDownloadURL()` on a Storage reference.

If the file is downloaded by someone using that download URL, you will be charged for the data that is transferred as shown in the [Firebase pricing page](https://firebase.google.com/pricing).

Comment: bonus points for linking to official docs stating this from Firebase.  I couldn't find it.