# How to store Firebase Storage Items to local cache to save bandwidth costs?

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, caching, firebase-storage

I'm enrolled in a project using Flutter and Firebase and I'm having trouble with bandwidth limits. The free quota is 1gb per day and I have a list with 100 images (and some files).

Is there a way to minimize the bandwidth costs through caching this files in local phone cache to not have to get the items from DB each time I open the screen?

Is there a package or something like this to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `CachedNetworkImage` [package](https://pub.dev/packages/cached_network_image) to avoid downloading the image every time. It's simple to use and you just need to pass the URL to the Widget:

```dart
CachedNetworkImage(
        imageUrl: "http://via.placeholder.com/350x150",
        placeholder: (context, url) => CircularProgressIndicator(),
        errorWidget: (context, url, error) => Icon(Icons.error),
     ),
```

To control how long the image is cached*, make sure you add cache header to your images when you upload them so they get cached properly (in the browser too if you're using flutter web):

```dart
    final contentType = 'image/*'; 
    final cacheControl = 'public, max-age=31556926'; // seconds -- ie 31556926 == one year
    final uploadTask = reference.putData(
        image.data,
        SettableMetadata(
          cacheControl: cacheControl,
          contentType: contentType,
        ));
```

So make sure to store the URL of the images when you upload them and just pass the URL to the users to get the images instead of downloading the images directly from FirebaseStorage in case you're doing that.

*I believe the package default is 7 days if no cache header is available but I cannot confirm.

Comment: I haven't seen it rigth

Comment: Does `FirebaseStorage.instance.ref().child(path).getDownloadURL();` already trigger a 'read' of the quota?

Comment: @progNewbie No, according to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60078403/10976714).

Comment: How can I control To control how long the image is cached in Firestore?

Answer (score 3):

I think you can do it easily with [cached network image](https://pub.dev/packages/cached_network_image)

If you want more control, I created a simple function to do this job, you can customize it further according to your needs:

```dart
import 'dart:typed_data';
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:http/http.dart' show get;

Future<File> getCachedImageFile(final String imageId) async {
  final Directory temp = await getTemporaryDirectory();
  final String fullPathName = '${temp.path}/images/$imageId';
  final File imageFile = File(fullPathName);
  if (imageId == null) return null;
  if (await imageFile.exists() == false) { // will guarantee that you don't make the API request (or just get image from url if unprotected)
    final String endpoint = 'http://www.mywebsiteorRESTapi.com/'
    String imgUrl = endpoint + imageId + '.png';
    var response = await get(imgUrl);
    try {
      await imageFile.create(recursive: true);
      if (response.bodyBytes != null)
        await imageFile.writeAsBytes(response.bodyBytes);
        return imageFile;
    } on Exception catch (exception) {
      throw 'could not write image $exception';
    }
  }
  return imageFile;
}
```

In your FutureBuilder:

```dart
future: getCachedImageFile('1VsSbB4Kh7Ab7spjQBA');

...

return Image.file(snapshot.data)
```