# Can you get Firebase FireStorage image URL that ends in .JPG/.PNG without alt or token params?

Tags: firebase, firebase-storage

We have a requirement that image URLs must end with .jpg or .png without any additional parameters, but Firebase gives us `https://...?alt=media&token=xyz`, is there a way just to get `https://...jpg`?

For token, [I can open up the auth rules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46153828/access-url-without-token-in-firebase-storage), but how can I get rid of `alt=media` as well?

We are using Mixpanel to track analytics and it has a feature that displays user profile photos if we specify a link. The problem is that it only parses URLs that end in .jpg or .png and doesn't work with URLs that have params.

We could upload it to imgur or a similar service, but we first wanted to try out with Firebase.

```
let newProfilePhotoStorage = Storage.storage().reference().child("profile_photos").child("\(currentUser.uid)").child("photo.jpg")     
newProfilePhotoStorage.putData(imageData, metadata: nil) { (metadata, error) in
    newProfilePhotoStorage.downloadURL { (url, error) in
        // URL
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you edit your question to include the code (or steps) of how you get the URL for the image?

Comment: Thanks @FrankvanPuffelen. Added example code.

Comment: Hmm... that code looks fine. I didn't realize that download URL still added an `alt` param. I'm not sure how to get a URL without it in that case. :-/