# Access Firestore Image without accessToken

Tags: angular, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-storage, access-token

I tried to create a 360-degree image viewer in my Angular app.
then I have this kind of piece of code

```
ngAfterViewInit(): void {
 this.panoViewer = new PanoViewer(
   this.pano.nativeElement,
   {
     image: 'https://pixexid.com/img/8hw0clw-360-panorama-miami.jpeg'
   }
 );
}
```

This code is completely working. But I need to replace image URL with firestore image URL like this.
"https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/lankaproperties-bf59b.appspot.com/o/images%2F360.jpeg?alt=media&token=15ba119a-ea23-4c79-be34-860691d28382"

But my component is not working with this URL because of the Access token. I need a URL in the format of "http://xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/xx.jpeg"

How can I do this?

Comment: You can't remove the access token.  That's what allows anonymous access to the object referenced by the URL. You will have to find another way to provide a URL to the object. https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-public-data

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Access url without token in Firebase Storage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46153828/access-url-without-token-in-firebase-storage)