# Firebase Storage - Not using Tokens

Tags: firebase, firebase-storage

I need to store profile images, and in order to fetch the right profile image I'm using the userid as the filename. However, each upload I want to save it as the same filename.

I've followed the answer on https://stackoverflow.com/a/61129057/1012500 and I'm able to access the file publicly without signing in. However, my uploads still contain a access token.

I'm uploading it using flutter. Is there anything else I need to do so that I don't use the token to get the latest version of the file ?

[image]

Comment: I don't understand what the problem is with the access token.  What are your requirements here?

Comment: hi doug, I don't want to reference the file based on the token to get the latest version of the file. In my scenario I want to store the profile pictures, and i'm using the filename using a userid (i.e using convention). When the user uploads a new image I can only access the update of the file using the token.

Comment: For example the user id is SInsKvnvLEQQp3OHKBI6mNHShAE3 and I was expecting to fetch it using http://<mybucket>.storage.googleapis.com/images/profile/full/SInsKvnvLEQQp3OHKBI6mNHShAE3.png but this doesnt get the latest version. https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/<mybucket>/o/images%2Fprofile%2Ffull%2FSInsKvnvLEQQp3OHKBI6mNHShAE3.png?alt=media&token=602bf89c-8e87-4ca4-9953-771a630be3b6 gets the latest version of the file. removing the token part : https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/<mybucket>/o/images%2Fprofile%2Ffull%2FSInsKvnvLEQQp3OHKBI6mNHShAE3.png doesn't return the image